# How to hide the parent class method from the child class object?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, c#-4.0

I want to `hide the parent class method for the the child class object.` My Circle object display two methods to me when I going to access that methods:

[image]

[image]

Here `objShape` is the object of the Shape class which is the abstract class.

I want to hide method which is display on 2nd image.

Here Circle class extends the Oval class and Oval class extends the Shape class.

Shape class coding

```
abstract public class Shape
    {        
        public abstract double Area(double dNum1 = 0.0, double dNum2 = 0.0);


        public abstract double Perimeter(double dNum1 = 0.0, double dNum2 = 0.0);

    }
```

Oval class Coding

```
class Oval : Shape
    {
        public override double Area(double dNum1 = 0.0, double dNum2 = 0.0)
        {
            double dAns = Math.PI * dNum1 * dNum2;
            return dAns;
        }

        public override double Perimeter(double dNum1 = 0.0, double dNum2 = 0.0)
        {
            double dTmp1, dTmp2, dAns;

            dTmp1 = 2 * (dNum1 * dNum1);
            dTmp2 = 2 * (dNum2 * dNum2);
            dAns = (Math.PI / 2) * Math.Sqrt(dTmp1 + dTmp2);

            return dAns;
        }      
    }
```

Circle Class Code

```
class Circle : Oval
    {

        public double Area(double dNum1)
        {
            double dResult = base.Area(dNum1, dNum1);
            return dResult;
        }

        public double Perimeter(double dNum1)
        {
            double dAns = base.Perimeter(dNum1, dNum1);
            return dAns;
        }

    }
```

So, Here how can I hide the direct access of the Oval class method for the Circle class object. In 2nd image it display the suggestion and I can use that method, but I don't want that suggestion and I don't want use that method with Circle class object.

Comment: @un-lucky Okay, But how can I implement that ? I also want to create the object for the Oval class.

Comment: @un-lucky, And I also have to extends the Oval class for the Circle Class.

Comment: @un-lucky - a sealed class is NOT the way to go here.

Comment: Obviously your interface/abstract class is broken. When there are shapes that should have an area based on two parameters there should either be no such method in the abstract one at all or your circle should derive from soem other class.

Answer (score 7):

> In 2nd image it display the suggestion and I can use that method, but I don't want that suggestion and I don't want use that method with Circle class object.

Then you shouldn't make `Circle` derive from `Oval`, basically. Don't forget that it would be perfectly acceptable to have a variable of type `Oval` which has a value at execution time referring to an instance of `Circle`:

```
Oval x = new Circle();
Console.WriteLine(x.Area(10, 20));
```

Fundamentally, any operation that makes sense for the base class *should* make sense for the derived class as well, in a sensible inheritance hierarchy.

If you want to keep your inheritance hierarchy, you should consider a redesign such that the radius etc are part of the *state* of the object, instead of being passed in as parameters. For example:

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    public abstract double Area { get; }
    public abstract double Perimeter { get; }
}

public class Oval
{
    private double Width { get; }
    private double Height { get; }

    public override double Area { get { ... } };
    public override double Perimeter { get { ... } };

    public Oval(double width, double height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
    }
}

public class Circle
{
    public double Radius { get { return Height; } }

    public Circle(double radius) : base(radius)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: And of course they both inherit from `Shape` having `public abstract double Area { get; }`. Same for `Perimeter`.

Comment: @IvanStoev: Yes. Will add that.

Comment: I want to pass the parameter with the `Area` and `Perimeter` method. As you know Circle need only one argument `Radius` and Oval need two arguments `Minor Axes` and `Major Axis`. It is possible with that and with the my class design. And I also want the same inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: @KalpeshRajai: Then your design is broken - it's as simple as that. You can't treat a `Circle` instance like an `Oval`, therefore `Circle` shouldn't derive from `Oval`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Okay, Thank you so much for help, By the way I am new in c#  and also thanks for your book. That help so much for start learning c#.

Comment: It's nice and my honour to talk with you.

Answer (score 0):

Just have Circle inherit shape as opposed to oval if you dont want the oval methods exposed by circle.

Comment: I want the same inheritance hierarchy. I don't want to circle to extends the Shape class. If I do that so Area method of the Circle class two arguments. I also don't want to give two arguments to the Area method of the circle class.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by changing your access specifier of Shape and Oval class methods to protected.

```
abstract public class Shape
{        
    protected abstract double Area(double dNum1 = 0.0, double dNum2 = 0.0);


    protected abstract double Perimeter(double dNum1 = 0.0, double dNum2 = 0.0);

}
```

and

```
class Oval : Shape
    {
        protected override double Area(double dNum1 = 0.0, double dNum2 = 0.0)
        {
            double dAns = Math.PI * dNum1 * dNum2;
            return dAns;
        }

        protected override double Perimeter(double dNum1 = 0.0, double dNum2 = 0.0)
        {
            double dTmp1, dTmp2, dAns;

            dTmp1 = 2 * (dNum1 * dNum1);
            dTmp2 = 2 * (dNum2 * dNum2);
            dAns = (Math.PI / 2) * Math.Sqrt(dTmp1 + dTmp2);

            return dAns;
        }
    }
```

[image: This will look like]

I think this is what you are looking for..

Comment: No that's not possible. I also have the Rectangle class which extends the Shape class. And If I do that so I got error: `Error 'Shape.Shape.Area(double, double)' is inaccessible due to its protection level`